# Does jquery $.when().done() wait for all $.ajax().done()'s to complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am pretty new to promises and am trying to be sure I have the right approach. My question is, when using `$.when` with a list of `$.ajax` calls, does the `.done` of the `$.when` wait to execute until all the `.done`'s of all `$.ajax` calls are finished? Perhaps this code snippet will help explain the question:

```
var apiSoftFail = false;

var myCallback = function(jsonData) {
  // lets say the json data returned by the ajax call contains a boolean
  // indicator of whether or not the purpose for doing the api call was successful
  if (jsonData.success) { 
    // do things with the jsonData returned
  } else {
    apiSoftFail = true; 
  }
};

var apiRequest = function(endpoint,callback) {
  return $.ajax(
    {'url':endpoint,'contentType': 'application/json'}
  ).done(function(data) {
    callback(data)
  });
};

$.when(
  apiRequest("/apiEndpoint1",myCallback),
  apiRequest("/apiEndpoint2",myCallback),
  apiRequest("/apiEndpoint3",myCallback)
).done(function() {
  if (apiSoftFail) {
    // "API Soft Fail"
    doThisFailureFunction();
  } else {
    doThisSuccessFunction();
  }
}).fail(function() {
  // "API Hard Fail"
  doThisFailureFunction();
});
```

Thanks in advance for any insight you can provide or suggestions you have for better ways of doing this.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Kevin. I think I have my syntax errors fixed and `callback` is being passed to `apiRequest` as `myCallback` which is defined, yes? Again, I am not very experienced in all this and welcome any suggestions for improving this construct.

Comment: you're right darick, he was wrong about that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you just had a few problems with your code. In particular, you need to give `done` a function.

```
.done(function() {
  if (apiSoftFail) {
    // "API Soft Fail"
    doThisFailureFunction();
  } else {
    doThisSuccessFunction();
  }
}
```

You can check here: The api calls will all call their own callbacks first and output their results, then "success" will be printed after.

If you run this snippet a couple of times, you'll see the individual requests do not run in a defined order (some will sometimes complete before others), but the "success" print will always come last.

```js
var apiSoftFail = false;

var myCallback = function(jsonData) {
  // lets say the json data returned by the ajax call contains a boolean
  // indicator of whether or not the purpose for doing the api call was successful
  if (jsonData) {
    console.log(jsonData);
    // do things with the jsonData returned
  } else {
    apiSoftFail = true; 
  }
};

var doThisFailureFunction = function() {

}

var doThisSuccessFunction = function() {
  console.log("success");
}

var apiRequest = function(endpoint,callback) {
  return $.ajax(
    {url:endpoint,'contentType': 'application/json'}
  ).done(function(data) {
    callback(data);
  });
};

$.when(
  apiRequest("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",myCallback),
  apiRequest("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2",myCallback),
  apiRequest("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/3",myCallback)
).done(function() {
  if (apiSoftFail) {
    // "API Soft Fail"
    doThisFailureFunction();
  } else {
    doThisSuccessFunction();
  }
}).fail(
  // "API Hard Fail"
  doThisFailureFunction
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Excellent answer and thanks for adding the additional code to help prove the result. I very much appreciate your response!

Comment: if it answered your question please mark it correct :)

Comment: Done... was just looking for that. This is my first post, so I am learning how all this works. Tried to "up arrow" your post, but it says I don't have enough reputation points to effect the post score. Thanks again!